# Servicestack with Autofac not resolving IRequestContext

Tags: servicestack, autofac, ormlite-servicestack

I am trying to use the Cache facilities of Service Stack. These are accessed through the
RequestContext, which is injected by the IOC in your Service.

This works as expected if you are using the default Funq IOC, it does not work when you hook AutoFac,  RequestContext is null and I am not sure how to configure autofac to build it. Any clues here? My AutoFac configuration:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

//Now register all dependencies to your custom IoC container

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(new[] { typeof(AppHost).Assembly })
       .PropertiesAutowired(PropertyWiringFlags.AllowCircularDependencies)
       .AsImplementedInterfaces()
       .SingleInstance();

container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());

IContainerAdapter adapter = new AutofacIocAdapter(builder.Build());
container.Adapter = adapter;
```

**EDIT:**

My Service already extends ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Service:

```
public class UserDetailsService : ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Service
```

which implements IRequiresRequestContext, RequestContext is null. If I remove autofac then it works as expected. With Autofac RequestContext is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RequestContext is not meant to be injected by an IOC, it's a special property that is set by ServiceStack if your Service requests it by implementing the `IRequiresRequestContext` interface. E.g.

```
public class MyClass : IService, IRequiresRequestContext {
    //injected by ServiceStack at run-time (per request)
    public IRequestContext RequestContext { get; set; } 
}
```

This is the same mechanism how the RequestContext property gets populated in the convenient default [Service](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Service.cs) base class in ServiceStack.

Comment: Just checked the code, I can't see how this can happen. I've [added an issue here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/issues/416) so I wont forget to create a small project to look at this when I have time.

Comment: Thanks for that I had opened an issue before as well, so You might want to merge them:https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/issues/414. Thanks again. And by the way ServiceStack rocks. Awesome piece of work

Comment: Nevermind I got it to work!!! Not sure what happened there, nothing has changed but now it's not null....Maybe The DevServer didnt restart properly and Aphost init was not run...Sorry for the trouble