# Problems integrating NServiceBus with ServiceStack IRequiresRequestContext

Tags: unity-container, servicestack, nservicebus

I am looking to integrate NServiceBus into an existing ServiceStack web host. ServiceStack is currently using the built in Funq IoC container. NServiceBus has been configured (elsewhere in the system) to use Unity for IoC.

ServiceStack has a feature whereby [IRequestContext will be automatically injected](http://www.servicestack.net/docs/framework/accessing-ihttprequest) when it finds  the `IRequiresRequestContext` interface on a class. NServiceBus has a similar feature for Message Mutators, via the `IMutateOutgoingTransportMessages` interface.

The application is a multi-tenant application. Single application, which via an API Key, passes an account code through to the NServiceBus handler (indirectly via a provider that is called on the construction of the handler's constructor injection using Unity).

My problem arises in ServiceStack. I am using a request filter to drag the API key out of the request headers, which I look-up in a database, and then finally write into the `IHttpRequest.Items` collection:

```
appHost.RequestFilters.Add((req, res, requestDto) =>
{
    var tenant = tenantRepository.GetByApiKey(
    req.Items.Add("AccountCode", tenant.AccountCode);
}
```

I then have an NServiceBus transport message mutator, that implements that IRequiresRequestContext interface, and this class is located in the same assembly as the ServiceStack services registered in the AppHost:

```
public class MessageHeaderMutator : IMutateOutgoingTransportMessages, INeedInitialization, IRequiresRequestContext
{
    #region IRequiresRequestContext Members

    public IRequestContext RequestContext { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region IMutateOutgoingTransportMessages Members

    public void MutateOutgoing(object[] messages, NServiceBus.TransportMessage transportMessage)
    {
        transportMessage.Headers.Add("AccountCode", RequestContext.Get<IHttpRequest>().Items["AccountCode"].ToString());
    }

    #endregion

    #region INeedInitialization Members

    public void Init()
    {
        Configure.Instance.Configurer.ConfigureComponent<MessageHeaderMutator>(DependencyLifecycle.InstancePerCall);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

However, RequestContext is never injected, and is always `null`. My theory is that the two interface injections, injected via the two separate frameworks, are somehow clashing.

I have a workaround, which is to use the ServiceStack `HostContext.Items` instead, as per [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16272702/119624), but I am concerned that the `HostContext` is not a per request collection, so I might end up writing data to the wrong tenant. Workaround is:

```
// app host
appHost.RequestFilters.Add((req, res, requestDto) =>
{
    var accountCode = tenantRepository.GetByApiKey(
    HostContext.Instance.Items.Add("AccountCode", client.AccountCode);
}


// message mutator
public class MessageHeaderMutator : IMutateOutgoingTransportMessages, INeedInitialization
{
    #region IMutateOutgoingTransportMessages Members

    public void MutateOutgoing(object[] messages, NServiceBus.TransportMessage transportMessage)
    {
        var accountCode = HostContext.Instance.Items["AccountCode"].ToString();
        transportMessage.Headers.Add("AccountCode", accountCode);
    }

    #endregion

    #region INeedInitialization Members

    public void Init()
    {
        Configure.Instance.Configurer.ConfigureComponent<MessageHeaderMutator>(DependencyLifecycle.InstancePerCall);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

My question is therefore twofold:

1. The first is, why does `IRequiresRequestContext` not correctly inject `RequestContext` into the Message mutator, or is there a way to [inject RequestContext manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494256/servicestack-with-autofac-not-resolving-irequestcontext)?
2. Is the use of the     `HostContext` safe to assume it is **per request**?
3. Bonus question: Is the use of two separate IoC containers in the same project (Unity in NServiceBus and Funq in ServiceStack) a really bad idea? Would it be smarter to get ServiceStack to use the same Unity IoC container as NServiceBus?

P.S. This is NServiceBus 4 (beta at time of writing).

Answer (score 1):

It is precisely because you're using 2 different containers that DI doesn't work for you out of the box for objects registered in different containers.

You don't necessarily need to standardize on a single container (though it would save you from dealing with these sorts of issues all the time).

What you can do to keep working with both containers is to tell the NServiceBus container how to resolve IRequiresRequestContext like this:

```
public class RequestContextBootstrapper : INeedInitialization
{
   public void Init()
   {
      Configure.Component<IRequiresRequestContext>( /* get object from ServiceStack */ );
   }
}
```

Comment: Funnily enough, I had already tried this. I got stuck at /* get object from ServiceStack */ :-)

Comment: I don't know anything about ServiceStack so I don't think I can help you there - sorry.

Comment: No problem. Thanks Udi. I have a workaround. I need to run some tests to make sure it is reliable.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the ServiceStack container via AppHostBase.Container and use it to resolve your objects as Udi suggested.